# How to get a new device token after deleteToken in fcm flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My usecase is when user logout need to avoid sending notifications (deleteToken user). and when he again loggedin need to send the notifiations (need to generate new device fcm token).

After calling deleteToken method, and calling getToken returns previous one, not newer.

Comment: Based on this document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#deleteToken() if "auto-init" is enabled a new token will be generated the next time the app is started. Is "auto-init" enabled in your app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: auto-init enabled